# Scheme Third, swap,evenatom a list

Tags: scheme

`(thirds '(a b c d e f g))` should return: `(a d g)`;

`(thirds '((a b) c (d e f) g (h i)))` should return `((a b) g))`

`(thirds '())` should return the empty list;

The second function is `SWAP`

The third function is `EVENATOM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all this functions were part of someone else's assignment, if you take the time to search for them there are several answers. Disclaimer: I'll link my own solutions, but there are others there, just as good.

- The `thirds` procedure was defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22827083/201359)
- The `swap` procedure was defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22795973/201359)
- And the `evenatom` procedure is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22821177/201359)

Comment: Appreciate your answer.

Comment: if you have could help me, please go to this address.  Really appreciate your time on my questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/22902820/2348617